# How to freeze gridview column in asp .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to freeze one specific column in an *ASP .net WebForm GridView*.

How can I do it. I prefer *jQuery*. 
I've already tried these links :

- [fixedheadertable.com](http://fixedheadertable.com/)
- [How to freeze header and left columns of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730451/how-to-freeze-header-and-left-columns-of-the-table)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "freeze"? Also, why did you try a plugin to freeze the *header* when you're trying to freeze a *column*? Are you trying to freeze the header as well? Do you have any example code of your situation as well? Have you tried writing anything to freeze a column? Links that don't solve your problem (neither had a solution for freezing a column) only show that you *tried* Googling a solution and failed to find a relevant link...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a column readonly(freeze)
if it is so write the below code

```
       ((BoundField)gridView1.Columns[columnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;
```