# Listview fixed header/left column

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have been handed some ASP.NET code and tasked with fixing the header and first column of the scrollable grid it contains.

I have found many, many posts on fixing headers/columns (e.g. [Table fixed header and first column css/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146581/table-fixed-header-and-first-column-css-html) / [Html table with fixed header column and row without JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759920/html-table-with-fixed-header-column-and-row-without-js) / [How to freeze header and left columns of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730451/how-to-freeze-header-and-left-columns-of-the-table)) but I have not been able to apply them successfully to my code. Any help you can provide would be awesome.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent3" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="mainPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListView>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="table1" class="tblstyle1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>th A</th>
                                <th>th B</th>
                                <th>th C</th>
                                <th>th D</th>
                                <th>th E</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>td content 1</td>
                        <td>td content 2</td>
                        <td>td content 3</td>
                        <td>td content 4</td>
                        <td>td content 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <div runat="server" id="xyz">
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="abc">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><%#:xyz %></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>td content 1</td>
                        <td>td content 2</td>
                        <td>td content 3</td>
                        <td>td content 4</td>
                        <td>td content 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>

                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>td content 1</td>
                        <td>td content 2</td>
                        <td>td content 3</td>
                        <td>td content 4</td>
                        <td>td content 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </asp:Panel></table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: You really can't "freeze" an element that is part of a larger element.  You're best off putting the table header into it's own div.  Freeze that.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing the header"?  Also asp and asp.net are two different things - you shouldn't use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy phrasing. By 'freezing' I mean fixing the table header row and the leftmost column so they do not scroll while the rest of the table does scroll.

Comment: Tell you what, forget it. I thought this place would be helpful but all I got was snark for using the wrong terminology. I actually used 'freeze' to suggest the 'freeze panes' behaviour in Excel and convey my requirements more concisely. How stupid of me! I should have written a vague question in pidgin English.